# This regex expression doesn't match 0 in second decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex expression: `/^[\<]{0,1}[0-9]{1}[\.]{1}[0-9]{2}$/`
Doesn't match with 0 in second decimal.
for example it accept 2.11 but doesn't accept 2.10
When i test in `regex101.com` everything is fine . but it doesn't in my code , i'm confused !

my full code:

```
  value='5.50';
  value.match(this.stringToRegex(/^[\<]{0,1}[0-9]{1}[\.]{1}[0-9]{2}$/))

  stringToRegex(s) {
  return new RegExp(s.match(/\/(.+)\/.*/)[1], s.match(/\/.+\/(.*)/)[1]);
  }
```

Comment: It works - https://regex101.com/r/mSUEGL/1

Comment: in my code it doesn't i'm working in angular

Comment: It is difficult to say what the issue is unless you post your code.

Comment: it works, bro. post your code so we can help you out

Comment: The regex is clearly correct, so the problem is something else. What that is, we cannot say since all we've been given is the (correct) regex.

Comment: I updated my post and give full code

Comment: Get rid of `stringToRegex(s)`. Use the regex directly: `if (/.../.test(value)) { return true; }`

Comment: Your code throws `s.match is not a function`. You should check if the input is a regex literal or a string instance first. Again, why not use `RegExp#test` directly?

Comment: i found that the problem reside in that when i input 5.50 it gives me 5.5 as a param in my function

Comment: this only happen when there's 0 in the second decimal . and of course 5.5 doesn't match my regex.